# Can one buy train ticket in Poland on automachines?

Tags: trains, poland

Or one has to go to a counter? I would expect some extra fee at the counter.

Comment: Is `automachines` some sort of special thing? Or do you just mean a normal ticket machine?

Comment: Just a ticket machine.

Comment: Why would there be a fee at the counter? Queue, I can certainly see, but a fee? (Certainly isn't any such thing in the UK)

Comment: I think in Germany there is such a fee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ticket machines (for trains) are not very common in Poland, you'd rather buy one at the counter. However, it is also possible that the counter will be closed (depending on how big the station is and what time of day it is) - in that case you can buy a ticket aboard from the train conductor, you should do this as soon as you get into the train, he should be available in the first compartment of the train, if not - wait for him.

The only extra fee will be charged when you buy the ticket at the train while counter at the station was open. Nonetheless ticket price will be the same at the counter and in the machine.